# Shopify Liquid - product collection conditional

Tags: shopify, liquid

Im trying to display a message when the user is at the cart that says 'you could save more' if the products in the cart match the targeted collection.

```
{% for item in cart.items %}

  {% assign product_collections = item.product.collections | map: 'title' %}

    {% if product_collections contains '5 for 20' and cart.item_count < 5 %}
      <span>you can get 5 for 20</span>
    {% endif %}

    {% if product_collections contains '4 for 10' and cart.item_count < 4 %}
      <span>you can get 4 for 10</span>
    {% endif %}

    {% if product_collections contains '3 for 10' and cart.item_count < 3 %}
      <span>you can get 3 for 10</span>
    {% endif %}

    {% if product_collections contains '3 for 35' and cart.item_count < 3 %}
      <span>you can get 3 for 35</span>
    {% endif %}

    {% if product_collections contains '3 for 20' and cart.item_count < 3 %}
      <span>you can get 3 for 20</span>
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Essentially I have 5 collections that contain products and as long as the quantities match, they will be saving money. So if the user has 5 products in the cart that all have the '5 for 20' collection, the total will be 20. The discounts are all working fine.

Problem is that if theres 2 products with the '5 for 20' collection, and 2 products with the '4 for 10' collection, the message only displays the 'you can get 5 for 20' since the cart total is more than 4.

Is there a way I can relate the cart items count to the collections count? Any pointers in the right direction would be great!

Comment: @senwmnv your issue needs more clarity

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure I understand the problem, but let's give it a try.

```
{% assign cat5_20 = 0 %}
{% assign cat4_10 = 0 %}
{% assign cat3_10 = 0 %}
{% assign cat3_35 = 0 %}
{% assign cat3_20 = 0 %}
{% for item in cart.items %}

  {% assign product_collections = item.product.collections | map: 'title' %}

    {% if product_collections contains '5 for 20' %}
        {% assign cat5_20  = cat5_20 + item.quantity %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if product_collections contains '4 for 10'  %}
        {% assign cat4_20  = cat4_10 + item.quantity %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if product_collections contains '3 for 10' %}
        {% assign cat3_10  = cat3_10 + item.quantity %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if product_collections contains '3 for 35'  %}
        {% assign cat3_35  = cat3_35 + item.quantity %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if product_collections contains '3 for 20'  %}
        {% assign cat3_20  = cat3_20 + item.quantity %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% if cat5_20 > 0 and cart.item_count < 5 %}
      <span>you can get 5 for 20</span>
    {% endif %}

{% if cat4_10 > 0 and cart.item_count < 4 %}
      <span>you can get 4 for 10</span>
{% endif %}

{% if cat3_10 > 0 and cart.item_count < 3 %}
      <span>you can get 3 for 10</span>
{% endif %}

{% if cat3_35 > 0 and cart.item_count < 3 %}
      <span>you can get 3 for 35</span>
{% endif %}

{% if cat3_20 > 0 and cart.item_count < 3 %}
      <span>you can get 3 for 20</span>
{% endif %}
```